# jquery 1.4.4 to jquery 1.8.0

Tags: jquery

How to rewrite this to use jquery 1.8.0? Whole site uses 1.8 library and just this script needs jquery 1.4.4. Please help to rewite this. Original of this script is http://perishablepress.com/demos/slide-fade-content/#first-item

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.more').live('click',function(){
                var href = $(this).attr('href');
                if ($('#ajax').is(':visible')) {
                    $('#ajax').css('display','block').animate({height:'1px'}).empty();
                }
                $('#ajax').css('display','block').animate({height:'200px'},function(){
                    $('#ajax').html('<img class="loader" src="loader.gif" alt="">');
                    $('#ajax').load('slide-fade-content.html #'+href,function(){
                        $('#ajax').hide().fadeIn().highlightFade({color:'rgb(253,253,175)'});
                    });
                });
                return true;
            });
        });
```

Comment: start with replacing `.live` to `.on`

Comment: have you tried switching? Just because plugin was written when 1.4 was available doesn't mean it can't be compatible. jQuery team has always been very conscious about backward compatibility. Newer versions (1.9+) are a  little more tricky.  `live()` is deprectaed but still works in `1.8`

Comment: it's not working :( sorry for that, but i don't know nothing except html and css

Comment: if i use 1.4.4 it's working, but when i use 1.8 it's doing nothing

Comment: code in the link provided should work fine. What errors are thrown in browser console?

Comment: no error. when i use 1.4.4 and click on button it shows content of slide-fade-content.html. but when i change library to http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js its doing nothing

Comment: oooops. this is error Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ##3
[Break On This Error]  

...eturn t?u.length:u?nt.error(e):L(e,a).slice(0)}function at(e,t,r){var i=t.dir,s=...

jquery....min.js (line

Answer (score 0):

You can use both versions of jQuery. 
Just give one of them a different namespace and check [jQuery.no.Conflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). I made this many times before.

I would recommend you to use other sliders or tabbing plugins like [cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) or [easytabs](http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/#tabs1-html)

Comment: i'm trying to do like on this site like at news. http://www.kendu.net/en/ which plugin is better?

Comment: my favorite is def. jquery cycle. its very well document with a lot of sample-implementations. Good Luck!